# import .bak to sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, backup

how can i import a .BAK file to my sql server 2005 ??
i have a backup data base made on sql and i want to import it on  sql server 2005. how can i do it !!!

thanks

Comment: 7 questions, no votes, no accepted answers. No interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by GUI or by a script just like that

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorksNew] 
    FROM  DISK = N'\\nas\Backup\L40\SQL2005\AdventureWorks_backup_200702120215.bak' 
    WITH  FILE = 1,  
    MOVE N'AdventureWorks_Data' TO N'C:\Data\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorksNew_Data.mdf',  
    MOVE N'AdventureWorks_Log' TO N'C:\Data\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorksNew_Log.ldf',  
    NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Read it [Here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/backup-and-restore-in-sql-server-full-backups)

Answer (score 2):

RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM DISK = 'C:\Temp\MyBackup.BAK'